# Change table row colour when checkbox is checked using CSS3 selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to change the colour of a row in a table when a checkbox in the row is checked using only CSS selectors?

I have the following, but it changes the colour of the checkbox, not the table cells:

```
.table_class tr td.column0 input[type="checkbox"]:checked { background-color:#f00; }
```

Comment: Essentially what you're asking for is a parent selector, which doesn't exist (yet) in CSS. The reason you're only able to change the color of the checkbox is because the snippet you posted targets/selects the checkbox, not the parent table cell.

Comment: That's what i figured :(

Answer (score 3):

You could use a little bit of JS? This would act like a checkbox, without having to use a checkbox. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39HFt/)

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
   $("table tr").css("background", "red"); //reset to original color
   $(this).css("background", "blue"); //apply the new color
});
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, that's not possible with pure CSS to work out both conditions of checkbox. This won't work in IE < 9 either. You will have to resort to javascript for that.